# Will my incognito mode recover after the computer had shut down?

Tags: private-browsing

I was browsing through memes and my fav youtubers videos in incognito mode since I didn't want my parents to find out that I'm wasting my time when I'm supposed to study.  Out of blue, my laptop made some weird noise while I was watching a YouTube video and the video suddenly changed to black and white checkers. The screen turned off and the noise was also not there anymore. I tried to turn it on again but it didn't work.

So, will the tabs opened in incognito mode be visible after the laptop has been fixed or will it be visible to the person fixing my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

> So, will the tabs opened in incognito mode be visible after the laptop has been fixed or will it be visible to the person fixing my laptop?

No. Browsers do not remember Incognito mode tabs at all – that's the whole point. Their state is not saved on disk, and as soon as the browser process exits for any reason (whether you quit it or whether the system shuts down) all information is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs will be closed on startup and nobody will see it, however, the cache won't be cleared. It shouldn't be visible to the person fixing it or your parents, unless he or they decide to ferret in your computer's cache and manages to decode them.

Comment: In most browsers, Incognito mode only uses memory cache by design.

Answer (score 0):

The data "should" be deleted as long as the PC is really shut down or all browser windows are closed. Technically the technician could see some of what you were doing, but it would take time and effort he would be unlikely to spend without good cause and pay.

I would not use incognito to hide information that could be damning or illegal in your country. Or anything somebody would be motivated enough to pay to have done.

**note**

Windows 10 has a nasty habit of recovering opened apps so be sure it has shut down completely. If not, unplug for at least 10 minutes or long press the power button until it shuts down.